# Using kubernetes-secrets with Google Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Is it possible to use kubernetes-secrets together with Google Composer in order to access secrets from Airflow workers?

We are using k8s secrets with our existing standalone k8s Airflow cluster and were hoping we can achieve the same with Google Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Kubernetes secrets are not exposed to the Airflow workers deployed by Cloud Composer. You can patch the deployments to add them (`airflow-worker` and `airflow-scheduler`), but there will be no guarantee that they won't be reverted if you perform an update on the environment (such as configuration update or in-place upgrade).

It's probably easiest to use an Airflow connection (which are encrypted in the metadata database using Fernet), or to launch *new* pods using `KubernetesPodOperator`/`GKEPodOperator` and mounting the relevant secrets into the pod at pod launch.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes secrets are available to the Airflow workers. You can contribute the components for whatever API you wish to call to work natively in Airflow so that the credentials can be stored as a Connection in Airflow's metadata database, which is encrypted at rest. Using [Airflow connection](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections) involves storing the secret key in GCS with an appropriate ACL, and setting up Composer to [secure the connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/secure-connections.html).

You can write your own custom operator to access the secret in the Kubernetes and use  it. Take a look for [SimpleHttpOperator](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/http_operator/index.html) - this pattern can be applied to any arbitrary secret management scheme. This is for for scenarios that access external services that aren't explicitly supported by Airflow Connections, Hooks, and Operators.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @muscat. Can you expand a little bit on the SimpleHttpOperator idea, how could that work?

Comment: Actually, I have found another one, [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#secret-config), which allows for expose the secret as environment variable, is that works for you? Airflow workers can simply request pods to be built with only the secrets they need. Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/28/airflow-on-kubernetes-part-1-a-different-kind-of-operator/).